Capacitor biometry unwanted call
We have CapacitorJS 6.0.0 Angular 18.2.2 app which uses capacitor-native-biometric 4.2.2.
During new version release Android version was/is fine but Testflight/iOS version since this release calls biometry check every ~25 seconds (closest periodic feature in app is set to 30s but it does not intervene biometry at all). App always after few seconds stops to responding and after that unwanted FaceID check is called. We investigated app somehow is killed and then whole Angular app.component constructor is called, requesting also faceid check since app data were purged by killing it.
The question is what can cause this problem and/or if anything I missed within latest iOS/Capacitor changes can be source of this.
We tried different iPhones, emulators, lib versions, app reinstalls or even replacements of capacitor-native-biometric lib. The only possible source we found cdould be within NativeBiometric.isAvailable() call before first faceId check. Also <key>NSFaceIDUsageDescription</key> within info.plist file is unchanged since historical implementation of feature.

Show your code of where you have this at and where its running. Also that plugin is outdate and not being updated anymore. CapGo have a forked version thats working. : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@capgo/capacitor-native-biometric

Well, the problem was Posthog crashing whole app..

hey, engineer at posthog here, there can be a clash recently between angular's change detection and session replay's change detection. we've improved that recently and added this advice for other folk https://posthog.com/docs/libraries/angular#session-replay
Do open a support ticket from the posthog app if none of that helps, we'd love to see if there's more to improve here
